# How can I connect to InfluxDB through Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: python, influxdb, nginx-reverse-proxy, influxdb-python

I have Nginx running as a reverse proxy on a computer with only one open port. Through this port and Nginx I redirect the received requests to several internal servers. Now I need to run InfluxDB on this computer, but the client writing to InfluxDB is on another computer.
My first idea was to add a new location to redirect input requests since port 8086 is closed, for example:

```
location /databasets {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;       
        }
```

and then, with Python, I use:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='https://myurl', port=10000, 'root', 'root', dbname='mydb', path='databasets', ssl=True, proxies={"https": "https://myurl:10000/databasets"})
```

But so far it doesn't work, I have tried a couple of ways of configuring the nginx.conf file that I have seen on the internet and also changing the host / port in the Python client. I don't know if this is not possible, or on which side is the error, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the following config in your nginx config

```
location /databasets/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
    rewrite `^/databasets/(.*) /$1 break`;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

The input url needs to be rewritten

Comment: Thanks for your response, Unfortunately it does not work. After testing several combinations of URL, port, username, password, I always obtain an error related with the proxy: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myurl', port=10000): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=SHOW+DATABASES&db=mydb (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))).  I have to say that in the remote machine it works if I write https://myurl:10000/databasets/query in the web browser  -> {"error":"missing required parameter \"q\""}